# Compare 2 Strings in Python

Tags: python, string

So, I need to figure out a program that when you input 2 different strings of the same length it will return NOT print the number of differences between the two strings. The order of the characters matters as well.

For example if you input `("abcdef", "aabccf")`
it should return 4.

`("abcdef", "accddf")` should return 2.

All I have so far is:

def differencecount ( A, B):
    counter = 0
    str1 = list (A)
    str2 = list (B)
    for letter in str1:
        if letter == str2:
            counter = counter + 1
    return counter

All this does is return 0 though so I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: what happens if x and y are different lengths? what is the expected output?

Comment: I was thinking of adding len (x) = len (y) to make sure they're equal in length. If they aren't equal in length I'll probably add a print 'Please enter strings of equal length' at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I would use

```
def difference(word_one, word_two):
    return sum(l1 != l2 for l1, l2 in zip(word_one, word_two))
```

Which works like

```
>>> difference('abcdef', 'abcdef')
0
>>> difference('abcdef', 'abcabc')
3
```

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to be doing this person's homework for them :/

Answer (score 1):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the strings together and then count how many different pairs there are:

```
def chardifferencecounter(x, y):
    return len([1 for c1, c2 in zip(x, y) if c1 != c2])

>>> chardifferencecounter('abcdef', 'aabccf')
4
>>> chardifferencecounter('abcdef', 'accddf')
2
```

**Explanation:**

Zipping the strings together produces this:

```
>>> s1 = 'abcdef'
>>> s2 = 'aabccf'
>>> zip(s1, s2)
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('e', 'c'), ('f', 'f')]
```

so it takes a character from the same position in each string and pairs them together. So you just need to count how many pairs are different. That can be done using a list comprehension to create a list with those pairs that are the same filtered out, and then get the length of that list.

Comment: @Pichu2016: didn't I already explain that in the answer? Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a different look here is a solution that doesn't use `zip` or `enumerate`:

```
def chardifferencecounter(x,y):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise Exception('Please enter strings of equal length')
    return sum(x[i] != y[i] for i in range(len(x)))
```

Note that this solution also raises an exception when `x` and `y` are of different lengths, which is what you wanted in your comment.